# how to query to convert the content size column to GB?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I uploaded a 26KB document.
I queried on database and the a column for content_size 25890.
I need to query on database the document and the content size should be in GB.
Is it possible to convert the value in column content_size into GB?

Comment: Just divide content_size by 1000000 in the select clause of your statement

Comment: @mbieren do you know why the 26KB file that I uploaded became 25890 content_size when I queried it on DB?

Comment: Because 25890 rounded is 26K?

Comment: Hi Adrian. Can I use 2 aggregate function like the sum of bytes and count of documents in query?